# Symbol.toStringTag defined but not being used by .toString method

Tags: javascript

I was trying to use `Symbol.toStringTag` in order to get `[object Pirate]` as a result whenever I try to call `.toString` on a Pirate instance, but I keep getting `[object Object]` back!

I already read [the ES6 spec for `toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring) and according to it my code should work. Maybe I'm missing something.

The code below is what I **expected** to happen:

```
function Pirate(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Object.defineProperty(Pirate.prototype, Symbol.toStringTag, {
    value: () => 'Pirate'
});

console.log(new Pirate('Jack Sparrow').toString()); // I expected '[object Pirate]'
```

Am I missing something here? I also checked to see if the `Pirate.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag]` was being set and it was.

Comment: Note that you can also use normal assignment: `Pirate.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'Pirate'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Pirate(name) {
  this.name = name;

  Object.defineProperty(this, Symbol.toStringTag, {
    get: function() {
      return "Pirate";
    }
  });
}
console.log(new Pirate('Jack Sparrow').toString());
```

Comment: Awesome! I should have set the getter for that property instead of setting its value. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is this - "toStringTag" is a *property* rather than an method. So if you change that in your code, it will work correctly.

Here, this is what I mean :

```
function Pirate(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Object.defineProperty(Pirate.prototype, Symbol.toStringTag, {
    /* value: () => 'Pirate' */ // change this to property
    value: 'Pirate'
});

console.log(new Pirate('Jack Sparrow').toString()); // I expected '[object Pirate]'
```

and you will have your result !

Answer (score 0):

For use inside a node_module for Electron, I had to set it `enumerable` to get it work:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Pirate.prototype, Symbol.toStringTag, {
  value: 'Pirate',
  enumerable: true
});
```